# Getting different time zone offsets for same time zone?

Tags: php, date, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

I have 2 strings with times in it and I need the Unix time stamp of them but with the correct time zone offset but I get 2 different time zone offsets from the same time zone.

```
Wed, 01 Apr 2020 12:00:00 +0200
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2020-04-01 12:00:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
)
Sat, 28 Mar 2020 12:00:00 +0100
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2020-03-28 12:00:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's summer and winter time. Berlin moved to DST on 2020-03-29. The summer time is +02:00.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint I do not think the question needs deletion. The issue is reproducible and has a simple explanation. Coaxing others into deleting is actually forbidden unless you explain why such question deserves deletion. Expected behaviour is not a reason for deletion.